# Ant run target even if depends target fails

Tags: java, email, ant, build

I have the following code in my build file

```
<target name="foo">
<some stuff>
</target>
<target name="bar" depends="foo">
<some other stuff>
</target>
```

When i do `ant bar` I want the `bar` target to run even if `foo` fails. How do I do this?

I dont want to use the try catch from ant-contrib.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, Ant is no a programming/script language. It's a build tool, so it has limitations.

For your requirement, I found this from the manual:

> -keep-going, execute all targets that **do not depend** on failed target(s)

Think about what "depend" is designed for. A target should not be executed when its dependency fails.

An alternative way is to go with `subant` (and of course, without `depends`).

```
<target name="foo">
    <fail message="fail" />
</target>

<target name="bar">
    <subant failonerror="false" target="foo">
        <fileset dir="." includes="build.xml"/>
    </subant>
    <echo message="still runs"/>
</target>
```

Which outputs:

```
bar:

foo:
   [subant] Failure for target 'foo' of: c:\Tools\files\build.xml
   [subant] The following error occurred while executing this line:
   [subant] c:\Tools\files\build.xml:11: fail
   [echo] still runs
```

But.. it looks ugly.

Another way is to implement your custom Ant entry point, and do whatever you want in it. Start your Ant with `ant -main <class> bar`.

If you want to stick with `depends`, and you have any task in `foo` which doesn't support `failonerror`, and you don't want `try-catch`, then I don't know how, either.

Comment: If i add multiple subants in a target does it run parallely? I have a suspicion that it does. Do you know anything about that?

Comment: If you just add multiple `<subant>`s to your target and want them to run parallely, check `<parallel>` task. If you use one `<subant>` task and nested `<fileset>` which selects multiple build files (just like what `<subant>`'s document shows), then AFAIK, there is no way to run them parallely.

Answer (score 3):

Consider [Antcontrib: TryCatch](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/trycatch.html)

```
<target name="foo">
  <some stuff>
</target>

<target name="bar">
  <trycatch>
    <try>
      <antcall target="foo"/>
    </try>
    <catch>
      <fail/>
    </catch>
    <finally>
      <some other stuff>
    </finally>
  </trycatch>
</target>
```